# How to get board view in odoo?

Tags: xml, odoo

I would like to use board view in a module. I want to make something like this... [image]

So i wrote some code from internet scources.[ref. odoo.com]

```
        <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="act_my_courses_tree">
              <field name="name">Tasks in Queue Tree</field>
              <field name="res_model">atm.surverys.management</field>
              <field name="view_type">form</field>
              <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
              <field name="domain">[('responsible_id','=','uid')]</field>
       </record>


       <record model="ir.ui.view" id="board_tasksinque_form">
            <field name="name">Tasks in Queue Form</field>
            <field name="model">board.board</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Tasks in Queue">
                <hpaned>
                    <child1>
                        <action string="Tasks in Queue" name="%(act_my_courses_tree)d"
                            colspan="2" />                          
                    </child1>
                </hpaned>

            </form>
        </field>

   </record>

  <record model="ir.actions.act_window" id="my_board">
        <field name="name">Tasks in Queue</field>
        <field name="res_model">board.board</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="usage">menu</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="board_tasksinque_form" />
  </record>
```

above code results as below image.
[image]

In another model i have created a tree that i want to put it over here in board view? any ideas

Thanks, Chandu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the quotes specified for uid. uid holds the value of currently logged in user.

```
<field name="domain">[('responsible_id','=',uid)]</field>
```